# Linux Live CD on a PowerMac G5 - permissions reading a dir on HFS Mac disk

Tags: linux, permissions

We have G5 PPC with Mac OS 10.xx (panther?).

I need files from it, but we don't have the passwords for the machine, and have no disks with which to recover data or reinstall the OS.

So, I used an Ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope 9.04 disk and mounted the drives, but when I try and open the target dir, I get permission problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to any other machine with Firewire simply start the G5 with the "t" button pressed. Keep it pressed while it boots and then you will see a firewire symbol on screen. Now your G5 acts as an external Firewire drive. You should be able to copy anything from the machine then.
You need to have HFS read features in Ubuntu though (sorry, I am not familiar with it and whether it is already built into the kernel).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing it with sudo? If you use a normal user, it *should* fail because of permission issues.